# How to setup italian voice language in freeswitch?

Tags: lua, freeswitch

Getting below error when i setup default Italian language.

```
table.insert(xml, [[<action application="set" data="default_language=it"/>]]);
```

Error :

```
2020-08-17 05:34:59.396425 [DEBUG] switch_ivr_play_say.c:70 No language specified - Using [it]
2020-08-17 05:34:59.396425 [ERR] switch_xml.c:3274 Can't find language it.
2020-08-17 05:34:59.396425 [DEBUG] switch_ivr_play_say.c:70 No language specified - Using [it]
2020-08-17 05:34:59.416382 [ERR] switch_xml.c:3274 Can't find language it.
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked this manual?

https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Speech+Phrase+Management

For each language you want to support you will need to load the appropriate mod_say_xx module in conf/autoload_configs/modules.conf.xml

Additionally you must update `conf/freeswitch.xml` accordingly.